# How to slice pandas series with hour stamps as index?

Tags: python, dataframe, timestamp, time-series

This is my time series:

```
Time
00:00:00    24.364387
00:01:00    24.509357
00:02:00    24.484649
00:03:00    24.476170
00:04:00    24.458480
00:05:00    24.439327
Name: Vals, dtype: float64
```

How can I access the values based on a specific index interval? Such as `myseries['00:02:00':'00:05:00']`? I thought I had to turn them into time stamps (but *hours, minutes, and seconds* only).

So I have turned it into a data frame:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Time':myseries.index, 'Vals':myseries.vals})
```

If I type `df.dtypes` I get:

```
Vals            float64
Time            object
dtype: object
```

So `Time` is an object and not a `datetime64[ns]`. Then I try to do: `df['Time'].dt.time` but then I get: `AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values`.

If I try: `df.loc['00:00:00':'00:05:00']`, I only get my headers. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my try:

`import datetime as dt
myseries = pd.DataFrame([24.364387,24.509357,24.484649,24.476170,24.458480,24.439327], index=pd.to_timedelta(['00:00:00','00:01:00','00:02:00','00:03:00','00:04:00','00:05:00']))
myseries.loc[dt.timedelta(minutes=1):dt.timedelta(minutes=3)]`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the function pd.to_datetime(Series). Here is the code:

```
df.Time = pd.to_datetime(df.Time)

df.dtypes
Time     datetime64[ns]
Vals           float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: It does not work. It says `TypeError: <type 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime`, but in reality my Time column is `object`.

Answer (score 1):

May be in your case, you don't need to convert at all.
When you turn the series to dataframe, do this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(myseries, columns=['Vals'])
```

Then try

```
df.loc['00:00:00':'00:05:00']
```